# computing pairwise bhattacharyya similarity

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to compute pairwise bhattacharyya similarities between classes in the fake data below. The aim is to compute the degree of multivariate similarity among different species for a series of variables. The original data are normal and homoscedastic, as in the following code.
However, when I try to  run the following code:

```
library(dyplr)
library(bio3d)

dummy.dataset<- data.frame(groups=c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",3),rep("D",3),rep("E",3)), X1=rnorm(15,0,1),X2=rnorm(15,0,1),X3=rnorm(15,0,1), X5=rnorm(15,0,1))

A.subset <–subset(dummy.dataset, groups=="A")
B.subset <–subset(dummy.dataset, groups=="B")

bio3d::bhattacharyya.matrix(cov(A.subset[,-1]), cov(B.subset[,-1]))#works

pairwise.bhattacharyya <- function (d, g){
    if (!is.factor(g)) {
        g = factor(g)
    }
    n = length(levels(g))
    N = n * n
    Z = matrix(rep(NA_real_, N), ncol = n)
    rownames(Z) = levels(g)
    colnames(Z) = levels(g)
    for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
        for (j in (i + 1):n) {
          Datax = subset(d, g == levels(g)[i])
          Datax.num <- dplyr::select(where(is.numeric))
          Datay = subset(d, g == levels(g)[j])
          Datay.num <- dplyr::select(where(is.numeric))
          Z[,j]<- bhattacharyya.matrix(cov(Datax.num),cov(Datay.num))
        }
      Z[i,]<- bhattacharyya.matrix(cov(Datax.num),cov(Datay.num))
    }
   return(Z)
}


pairwise.bhattacharyya(d=dummy.dataset, g=dummy.dataset$groups)
```

I get

```
Error in strsplit (pattern, NULL):
  "pattern" argument absent, with no default value
```

I suppose that the error come from bhattacharyya.matrix function...

Any clue?
Thanks

Comment: After some minor adjustments to the code such that it runs on my machine (add `library(tidyverse)`, use the proper assignment operator `<-` to create toy data, insert `Datax` and `Datay` in your `select(where(is.numeric))` bits of the code, the code returns a matrix as expected. I am not sure where the `strsplit` error comes from, but it means it did not receive the second argument properly. I suggest refactoring your code, and see if that solves or narrows down the problem.

Comment: Thank you! After your minor adjustments to the code, I discovered that the issues was related to the fact that I removed a levels in the full dataset and I tried to perform the function without droplevels(). Now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this :

```
library(dplyr)
library(bio3d)

dummy_dataset <- data.frame(groups = c(rep("A", 3),
                                       rep("B", 3),
                                       rep("C", 3),
                                       rep("D", 3),
                                       rep("E", 3)), 
                            X1 = rnorm(15, 0, 1),
                            X2 = rnorm(15, 0, 1),
                            X3 = rnorm(15, 0, 1),
                            X5 = rnorm(15, 0, 1))

A_subset <- subset(dummy_dataset, groups == "A")
B_subset <- subset(dummy_dataset, groups == "B")

bio3d::bhattacharyya.matrix(cov(A_subset[,-1]), cov(B_subset[,-1]))#works

pairwise.bhattacharyya <- function(d, g)
{
  if(!is.factor(g))
  {
    g <- factor(g)
  }
  
  n <- length(levels(g))
  N <- n * n
  Z <- matrix(rep(NA_real_, N), ncol = n)
  rownames(Z) <- levels(g)
  colnames(Z) <- levels(g)
  
  for(i in 1 : n) 
  {
    for(j in i : n) 
    {
      Datax <- subset(d, g == levels(g)[i])
      Datax.num <- dplyr::select_if(Datax, is.numeric)
      Datay <- subset(d, g == levels(g)[j])
      Datay.num <- dplyr::select_if(Datay, is.numeric)
      Z[i, j] <- bhattacharyya.matrix(cov(Datax.num),cov(Datay.num))
      Z[j, i] <- Z[i, j]
    }
  }
  
  return(Z)
}

pairwise.bhattacharyya(d = dummy_dataset, g = dummy_dataset$groups)

            A           B           C           D           E 
A 1.000000000 0.000000000 0.656992167 0.000000000 0.002159783
B 0.000000000 1.000000000 0.001994310 0.886010788 0.002096559
C 0.656992167 0.001994310 1.000000000 0.452426729 0.002014805
D 0.000000000 0.886010788 0.452426729 1.000000000 0.001925775
E 0.002159783 0.002096559 0.002014805 0.001925775 1.000000000
```

Comment: The results from the adapted code and your code are different. In the my code I got an NA at df[A, E] and repetition of the same number somewhere else. Your results seem more reasonable to me. However, could you explain to me this part? Z[j, i] <- Z[i, j] Thank you for your help!